# Authlogic and Roles

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, authorization, roles, authlogic

I am developing an application which users authlogic for authentication.

I would like some way of giving users roles so that I can authorize certain actions to certain roles.

Is there an 'out of the box' gem or plugin that suits this or would I be better build it from scratch.

What would you recommend?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ACL9 is what i currently use for the authorization, authlogic is the best match so i think you will do fine with it.

Check out the following 2 links for instructions.

https://github.com/be9/acl9/wiki/Tutorial:-securing-a-controller

http://github.com/be9/acl9/tree/master

Answer (score 3):

Cancan!

http://railscasts.com/episodes/192-authorization-with-cancan

http://github.com/ryanb/cancan

Answer (score 0):

I currently use authlogic for my authentication, with the basic role requirement stuff I posted above..

Edit:

This has been turned into a gem:

http://gemcutter.org/gems/easy_roles

Answer (score 0):

I'm using authlogic and [declarative_authorization](https://github.com/stffn/declarative_authorization/wiki) in my Rails apps.

Look at my rails app template: https://github.com/stffn/declarative_authorization/wiki